# Can this sentence be correct grammatically?

Tags: commas, clauses

Here is the sentence:

> Are we suddenly see a dozen or more sailing in the clear blue sky?

I have a bet with an editor that this sentence has a mistake, and it cant't be correct in this writing. I think there must be *Are we suddenly **seeing***. 

But my opponent declare there are invisible commas in it, and it must be interpreted like:

> Are, we suddenly see, a dozen or more sailing in the clear blue sky?

So, it's a *parenthetical clause* that we can throw out and the sentence will not lose its meaning.

Comment: Aagh **!** We suddenly see a dozen or more sailing in the clear blue sky.

Comment: Are we suddenly seeing a dozen? or more? sailing in the clear blue sky?

Comment: @Hugh the question is about not to count all the possible versions, but to confirm/disprove the sentence is wrong

Comment: What kind of editor would not see the mistake in that question? And would actually *bet money* that there wasn't one?

Comment: In practice no native speaker would make this statement. It would always be either ***Do** we suddenly see a dozen...* or *Are **there** a dozen...*. Discussing contrived interpretions of how to make OP's text "grammatical" are pointless.

Comment: Fire the editor. Either they can't admit to a simple oversight and are trying to come up with insultingly contrived reasons thinking you're an idiot, or they genuinely think that all they have to check for is theoretical syntactic possibility, but never probability, or the slightest hint of meaning, or the tiniest grain of style. Frankly I do not know which is worse. Fire them now.

Comment: @robusto the one that is willing to interpret it with the commas as placed and thinks he's being clever? I can't come up with any possible meaning of that sentence with the commas though. Though consider the the following "Are, as we come home, a dozen or more sailing in the clear blue sky?" I realize the "as" is doing the lion's share of work there but might it be one of those evil cases with strange interpretations: like "Girls boys deer cats chase butt like smile."

Comment: @DRF: Grammaticality is no assurance that something makes sense: 
"[Colorless green ideas sleep furiously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously)" . . .

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the parenthesis idea works at all.
Let's remove "we suddenly see":

> Are a dozen or more sailing in the clear blue sky?

Ok. (I'd love to know what are sailing in the blue sky).

So, what did we take out?

> we suddenly see

Either this means "see" literally; in which case we can count "them"
Or "see" means

> to be aware of - *[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/see)*

So, either way, if we *know* a dozen or more are sailing ... why do we then ask the question "are a dozen or more sailing?"

Reckon you're right, Nikoly. And even if it did make sense, it's appalling English.

("Are", we suddenly *ask*, "a dozen or more sailing in the sky?" might work.)

**Additional answer after seeing linked video in comment below**

I thought I heard "Now we suddenly see a dozen or more", but looking it up online I find:

> Are we seing (sic) a dozen or more? - [*http://genius.com/Ryan-adams-when-pigs-fly-lyrics*](http://genius.com/Ryan-adams-when-pigs-fly-lyrics)

Who knows what it is? Who cares? The editor's still wrong.

Comment: +1. Well argued. Another way of looking at it would be to take the parenthetical outside the sentence to its normal, canonical position and see how that works: and “We suddenly see, are a dozen or more sailing in the clear blue sky?” is quite obviously absolute arrant nonsense. You cannot _see_ something that’s a question.

Comment: https://youtu.be/ffhSkKviw1I?t=2m39s

Comment: Hang on. I suddenly see* from the video that it's "Now we suddenly see a dozen or more". No problem there. (* in the second sense of "see" above :-) ) Has this all been a waste of time? Quite good fun, though.

Comment: @Margana I had a suspicion there was "now". Actually I was looking for the lyrics and there was "now",  but I'm not native speaker, so in that pronunciation it's equal for me "now" and "are" ))

Comment: The Summer Silly Season's Started :-)

Answer (score 0):

"Are, we suddenly see, a dozen or more sailing in the clear blue sky?" - Incorrect.

There're commas, which if **used** (and visible), can change the meaning of the sentence. They don't change anything in the above sentence. Nor do they make the sentence appear correct or easily comprehensible.